# Trigger a Logic App from SharePoint JSON view formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, logic-app

Using SharePoint JSON view formatting you can trigger a Flow using the **executeFlow** custom row action and then providing the ID of the Flow to be triggered, for example:

```
"elmType": "button",
"customRowAction": {
  "action": "executeFlow",
  "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"2d8001c0-31f4-48e5-90ab-1804fa33bb43\"}"
},
"txtContent": "Start a flow",
```

Is it possible to trigger a **Logic App** using a similar approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JSON view formatting it's not possible to directly start a Logic App from a button action, based on the available attributes of the **customRowAction** property:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customrowaction

- **defaultClick**: buttons with this action will do the same thing as clicking the list item in an uncustomized view. Below is an example of a button that, when clicked, simulates a click on the item, which results in opening the list item. Adding this example button to a document library simulates a click on the file or folder, which results in the file or folder being opened.
- **share**: Clicking the button will open the sharing dialog. Below is an example of this type of button.
- **delete**: Clicking the button will open the delete confirmation dialog.
- **editProps**: Clicking the button will open the item properties page in edit mode.
- **openContextMenu**: Clicking the button will open the item's default context menu.
- **setValue**: Clicking the element will update the item with the field values provided.
- **executeFlow**: Clicking the button will launch the specified Flow, specified by ID inside the actionParams attribute. For an example of this, see Create a button to launch a Flow. Below is an example of this type of button.

Microsoft do have documentation that allows you to call a Logic App from Power Automate. I've not read the documentation in details but it seems there is the potential to trigger a Flow that triggers a Logic App.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/call-from-power-automate-power-apps

For my solution I used the **setValue** attribute of the customRowAction property in my JSON to change a field on the item (e.g. "Start" = true). Then I have my Logic App (which runs on an interval) get all items from the list/library and then filter those items where "Start" = true.